# As there was a fallen tree ... the path,I had to walk ... it to go to the other side

Tags: prepositions

> As there was a fallen tree ... the path, I had to walk  ... it to go to the other side.

Options:

- a). out of/in
- b). under/around
- c). out of/into
- d). along/along
- e). across/around

My Approach: I am confused between d) and e).

Reason:

I found **along** meaning  that correlated in the sentence like

> beside, by the side of, on the edge of, alongside.

Example: Trees grew along the river bank.

I found **across** meaning the following:

> from one side to the other of (something)

in other words, it is expressing movement over a place or region.

Can anyone guide me on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the definitions to the logical meaning of the phrases, it should be clear.

If:

> there was a fallen tree *along* the path

being beside/alongside the path you would not have to take the action in the second phrase:

> I had to walk...to go to the other side.

Only *across* (blocking the path) would result in such action:

> there was a fallen tree **across** the path

After establishing this, it follows that to get past the obstacle you have to go *around* it:

> I had to walk **around** it to go to the other side